# My app is detected as malware

Tags: malware-detection

**Situation**

There is an installer for desktop application. When it runs, it unpacks some executalbe files, executes them, writes to registry, etc. Every executable file and installer itself is written by out team, is not aimed to do any harm to user and is signed with valid security certificate. Anyway, one of executables is recognized as MSIL.downloader by Malwarebytes AntiMalware tool.

**Question**

How can we get rid of this behavior?

**Details**

- This issue was reported by several our clients. However, when I scan files with same tool on my machine, it does not detect any spyware in them.
- We have source codes for problem executable and can slightly rewrite them if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounter same problem:

The solution was to post support request to http://helpdesk.malwarebytes.org with description of situation and follow their instructions.